# Delete Row In a DataGrid for a WPF browser Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I m trying to build a WPF browser application after using a lot WinForms.
I don't find out the way to delete a row in my dataGrid.
The update and insert part work fine.
I've read a lot of answers about ObservableCollection, but I think it s not suitable in my case.

I tried this on:

```
foodSupplierDataGrid.Items.Remove(foodSupplierDataGrid.SelectedItem);
```

But it gives an error.

Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

So what should i do?

XAML

```
<

<Page

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:larotis_general_testDataSet x:Key="larotis_general_testDataSet"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="foodSupplierViewSource" Source="{Binding foodSupplier, Source={StaticResource larotis_general_testDataSet}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="#FF066E19" Margin="-463,-198,-465,-234">
        <dg:DataGrid x:Name="foodSupplierDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="296,134,288,224" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Loaded="foodSupplierDataGrid_Loaded" CanUserDeleteRows="True" />
        <Menu>
            ...
        </Menu>
        <Button x:Name="Delete" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="933,836,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Delete_Click"/>
    </Grid>


</Page>
```

**The code behind**

```
public partial class Supplier : Page
{
        larotis_general_testDataSetTableAdapters.foodSupplierTableAdapter adapter = new larotis_general_testDataSetTableAdapters.foodSupplierTableAdapter();
        larotis_general_testDataSet dataset = new larotis_general_testDataSet();
```

`public Supplier()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void foodSupplierDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        adapter.Fill(dataset.foodSupplier);
        this.DataContext = dataset.foodSupplier.DefaultView;

        dataset.foodSupplier.foodSupplierRowChanged += new larotis_general_testDataSet.foodSupplierRowChangeEventHandler(SupplierRowModified);
        dataset.foodSupplier.foodSupplierRowDeleted += new larotis_general_testDataSet.foodSupplierRowChangeEventHandler(SupplierRowModified);
    }



    void SupplierRowModified(object sender, larotis_general_testDataSet.foodSupplierRowChangeEvent e)
    {
        adapter.Update(dataset.foodSupplier);
    }

    private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }


}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it by myself.
It was quite simple.

```
 private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         dataset.foodSupplier.DefaultView.Delete(foodSupplierDataGrid.SelectedIndex);
         this.DataContext = dataset.foodSupplier.DefaultView;
    }
```